# NSMutableArray to NSDictionary and then add to an NSArray

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray

My app stores images in an NSMutableArray. I then call those objects and then send them through email in the mailSender.parts section of the code below. The problem is it only adds the first objectatindex when I need to add all objects. I am confused on how to make each image in the self.arrSlidshowImg NSMutableArray add to the vcfPart2 NSDictionary and then add it as an array object so the mailSender.parts will send all images. Any thoughts? I should also note that I did an NSLog to see the results adding this code NSLog(@"VCF: %@", vcfPart2);. The log file showed each value in vcfPart2. So the code is calling each response.

```
 NSDictionary *vcfPart2;
        for (int i = 0; i < self.arrSlidshowImg.count; i++) {
             NSData *vcfData = [self.arrSlidshowImg objectAtIndex:i];
             vcfPart2 = [JFMailSender partWithType:PartTypeFilePart
             Message:[vcfData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]
             ContentType:@"image/jpeg"
             ContentTransferEncoding:@"base64"
             FileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Individual_%d", i]];

        }

   mailSender.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart2,vcfPart2,nil];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [mailSender sendMail];
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following comes from a simple reading of your code, and among other things I have not looked up `JFMailSender`:

1. You declare a variable `vcfPart2` to hold a reference to a dictionary
2. You enter a loop
3. In the loop you assign a value to `vcfPart2`, this value is presumably a reference to a dictionary as you report no warnings
4. Step 3 is executed `self.arrSlidshowImg.count` times, ice per iteration of the loop
5. You exit the loop, at this point `vcfPart2` will hold the last reference assigned to it, the previous `self.arrSlidshowImg.count - 1` having been overwritten

Your concern appears to be that when you then use `vcfPart2` it only references one dictionary - but that is all it can ever do, that is it's type.

Maybe you intended to create a dictionary in your loop and then *add* that dictionary to a mutable array so that after the loop the array contains all the dictionaries?

HTH